# How to find common character matches in two strings having same length using PHP?

Tags: php, regex

How to find common character matches in two strings having same length using PHP?

For example,

```
$s1 = "ashyjUTY#rj[jkIIO}[hh{FIL]Ojk89y]";
$s2 = "pshyjUTY#r7[jk8rO}[hh{DrL]OjkB7y]";
cMatch($s1, $s2);
```

Output:

```
-shyjUTY#r-[jk--O}[hh{--L]Ojk--y]
```

The `cMatch` function will predict the common character matches like above.

**CODE**

```
<?php 
function cMatch($s1, $s2) 
{ 
 $p = $s1; 
 $r = $s2; 
 $m = str_split($p, 1); 
 $n = str_split($r, 1); 
 $a = count($m); 
 $b = count($n); 
 if ($a == $b) { 
   for ($i = 0; $i < $a; $i++) { 
      if ($m[$i] == $n[$i]) { 
        print $m[$i]; 
      } else {
        print "-"; 
      }
   } 
 } else { 
    print "Length of both strings are different!"; } 
 } 
 $x = "ashyjUTY#rj[jkIIO}[hh{FIL]Ojk89y]"; 
 $y = "pshyjUTY#r7[jk8rO}[hh{DrL]OjkB7y]";
 cMatch($x, $y); 
?>
```

Comment: This is quite simple, and smells of homework. What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: [@Amadan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/240443/amadan) I tried to split string to array of both and match both array using for loop.

Comment: Show us your code please.

Comment: Splitting is not necessary, you can access string's characters just like array. But, as Sergey says, show us your code, and describe what is wrong with it (is there an error? do you get wrong results? what wrong results?...)

Comment: `regex` will make things more complicated

Comment: @ak-SE.Thanks for marking. Glad to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Take a look to the below solution:-**

```
<?php
$s1="ashyjUTY#rj[jkIIO}[hh{FIL]Ojk89y]";
$s2="pshyjUTY#r7[jk8rO}[hh{DrL]OjkB7y]";
$already=""; // create an empty string
for($i=0;$i<strlen($s2);$i++) // start loop
{
   if ($s1[$i] == $s2[$i]) // done match of character at exact position in both string
   {
       $already .=$s2[$i]; // if match found then assign the character to the newly created variable
   }else{
       $already .='-'; // if not then add - to the variable
   }
}
echo $already; // print the variable and get the common characters along with - included too.
?>
```

Output:- https://eval.in/520701

**Note:-**

1. This code will match characters at same position in both string.
2. Also i believe that you can change it into function very easily.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it might help you.

```
<?php
$s1 = "ashyjUTY#rj[jkIIO}[hh{FIL]Ojk89y]";
$s2 = "pshyjUTY#r7[jk8rO}[hh{DrL]OjkB7y]";
$S1_arr = str_split($s1);
$S2_arr = str_split($s2);

$common = implode(array_unique(array_intersect($S1_arr, $S2_arr)));

echo "'$common'";
?>
```

Comment: This won't give you the "-" mask, it will only output the unique characters.

Comment: I am trying to print the output with same length. So, it'll be easy to compare.